# Create filename including punctuation

Tags: vba, ms-word, filenames

I am creating a Word template that will create the filename when saved.

In the second cell of the first table within the document there is a reference field, which will be something like:

```
P2457.0227178P1
```

Where, the first 5 characters are a case reference, then a full stop or 'period', then a 6 digit date (MMddyy), then a two digit suffix.

The period, date and suffix is automatically created by Word and the prefix is user-generated.

To get this to be the default filename on saving, the code below makes the contents of this cell the document title.
On saving, Word cuts off the document title before the full stop, so it only offers the prefix as the filename.

How can I get the whole reference as the default save filename?

```vb
Sub SaveAsFilename()
    Dim MyDocTitle As String
    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim oRng As Range
    
    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    oDoc.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(2).Select
    
    Set oRng = Selection.Cells(1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range
    oRng.End = oRng.Cells(1).Range.End - 1
    oRng.Select
    
    MyDocTitle = Selection.Text
    
    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSummaryInfo)
        .Title = MyDocTitle
        .Execute
    End With
    
    Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs).Show
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = MyDocTitle
    .Show
End With
```

Hope that helps.